# Logging messages with discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add a logging feature to my bot

I am trying to make the program output the text but it outputs the object reference instead

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message: str):
    ts = time.time()
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    with open("logs.txt", "a") as text_file:
        print(f"<{st}> {message}", file=text_file)
```

I was expecting something like this
if the message was "hello" at 2019-06-08 17:32
it would output

```
<2019-06-08 17:32:26> hello
```

but it just does

```
<2019-06-08 17:24:26> <discord.message.Message object at 0x0083C0A8>
```

Comment: Well, `message` obviously is not a `str` object then ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(f"<{st}> {message.content}", file=text_file)
```